# Games detect dual monitor setup as one giant monitor

Tags: multi-monitor, laptop

I have a laptop with an external monitor. Both have 1920x1080.

I want to play games in the laptop screen and use the external screen to monitor the laptop performance and temperatures (glances, nvidia-smi). The problem is that the games detect both screens as one and when choosing a resolution in video settings they jump from 1680x1050 to 3840x1200 (no 1920x1080).

How can I play games (in full screen) using only one monitor?

PS: I am using Pop_OS 19.10

Comment: You've mistakenly asked a technical question on the Meta discussion side of U&L. I will migrate the question to the main site.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am sorry. I didn't realize. Thank you for the migration.

Comment: 3840x1200 isn't 3840x1080. Sounds like whatever this game is just doesn't support 1920x1080 for some reason.

Comment: It happens with more than one game, and if I disconnect the external monitor it detects 1920x1080